Proposal to substitute the 'Neurobiology' with the 'Neuroscience' tag
Now that we have proposed our site to be renamed 'Psychology and Neuroscience' I like to bring up a point that has been bothering me a long time, namely the neurobiology tag.
As of now, the master tag is neurobiology, with the slave synonym being neuroscience. This means that whenever a person types in the latter, it gets auto-substituted by neurobiology.
I personally heavily prefer neuroscience over neurobiology and would in fact opt to

Swap neurobiology into the slave and make neuroscience the master;
Subsequently, and immediately merge the two such that neurobiology becomes obsolete.

Related post dating back to 2012

In answer to the unanimous support to the proposal, the mod team has swapped the neurobiology and neuroscience tags synonyms, making neuroscience the master, and neurobiology the slave (the synonym).
Update
Any badges earned will simply be replaced;thw system drops the Neurobiology badges and will award you with the corresponding Neuroscience ones. I for example just received the bronze Neuroscience badge and lost the Neurobiology one. 

Fig. 1. Screenshot right before merging
